# Как узнать дату изменения статуса заказа? woocommerce

Tags: wordpress

В админке меняем статус а на странице заказов определенного пользователя выводиться информация о заказе, как на скрине
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как достать эту дату ??
 `$order = wc_get_order($customer_order);` в этом обьекте нет даты изменения статуса. Есть дата последней модификации и дата создания но в этом нет смысла.

```
$notes = $order->get_customer_order_notes()
```

Comment: написать код, выводящий эту дату.

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли.
Как мне достать эту дату ни в $order ни в $notes нет этой даты. В чем проблема ответить в каких переменных лежат эти данные.
Или это является недостойным отвечать людям которые чего-то не знают?

Comment: не вижу кода ни с $order, ни с $notes

Comment: обновил.......................

Comment: видимо написать пользовательскую функцию извлечения даты из базы данных... так яснее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
function get_private_order_notes( $order_id){
    global $wpdb;

    $table_perfixed = $wpdb->prefix . 'comments';
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT *
        FROM $table_perfixed
        WHERE  `comment_post_ID` = $order_id
        AND  `comment_type` LIKE  'order_note'
    ");

    foreach($results as $note){
        $order_note[]  = array(
            'note_id'      => $note->comment_ID,
            'note_date'    => $note->comment_date,
            'note_author'  => $note->comment_author,
            'note_content' => $note->comment_content,
        );
    }
    return $order_note;
}
```